# LED Package/Case

Tags: led, identification, packages, cases

I could'not find the packaging searching online. Can you tell me the package/case types of the LED (right) and PD (left) below? Thanks in advance.

[image: sharp LED&PD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off the shape the one appears to be a Sharp Photo LED similar to [GL480](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sharp-microelectronics/GL480/425-1025-5-ND/457750). Unfortunately Obsolete.
[image]

I did not find an exact match, however I am thinking the other would be a matching Photo Trans. This is not it only an example [PT481FE0000F](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sharp-microelectronics/PT481FE0000F/425-2383-5-ND/720475)

[image]

Both are through hole right angle packages. Sorry I couldn't narrow down further.